Sharing video to Instagram from my iOS app
I have see few people already touched this subject, but I don't think anyone suggested 100% answer that will work.
Basically, I want to be able to share video from my IOS app to Instagram WITHOUT engaging UIActivityViewController. Since modifying UI of UIActivityViewController is not an option, I need to implement Instagram sharing option from scratch, and that is to call Instagram app from my app.
What I found out here on Stackoverflow, is that video has to be saved to the Gallery and then it can be shared via Insta. Here is the code I ended up using:
func requestAuthorization(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        if PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus() == .notDetermined {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion()
            }
        } else if PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus() == .authorized {
            completion()
        }
    }
    
    func saveVideoToAlbum(_ outputURL: URL, _ completion: ((String, Error?) -> Void)?) {
        
        var localIdentifier: String = ""
        requestAuthorization {
            PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                let request = PHAssetCreationRequest.forAsset()
                localIdentifier = request.placeholderForCreatedAsset?.localIdentifier ?? ""
                request.addResource(with: .video, fileURL: outputURL, options: nil)
            }) { (result, error) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                    
                    completion?(localIdentifier, error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func testInsta(_ videoUrl: URL) {
        
        saveVideoToAlbum(videoUrl) { localIdentifier, err in
            
            let u = "instagram://library?LocalIdentifier=" + localIdentifier
            let url = NSURL(string: u)!
            if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url as URL) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: u)!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            } else {
                
                let urlStr = "https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/instagram/id389801252?mt=8"
                if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                    UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: urlStr)!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                    
                } else {
                    UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: urlStr)!)
                }
            }
        }
    }

Although this code doesn't open this pretty UI in the scope of my app (like UIActivityViewController does), it still does the job. It opens the instagram with my video in it ready for editing. BUT, it opens my video only in case if Insta has a full access to my Gallery. Otherwise, it just shows me the last asset from my Gallery it has access to.
So my question is - how to share a content to Instagram directly from my app, regardless whether or not Instagram has a full access to the Gallery? The same way as UIActivityViewController does.
I am 100% it is possible to do what I want to do, but I am struggling to find a proper documentation that will explain how to achieve what I want. If someone already solved this challenge, please kindly share your findings. Thank you in advance!
